# XSLT - xsl choose

Tags: xslt

I have a problem i need to match two parameters in xsl choose clause, is there a way to achieving this?

for example: xsl:when test= i need to check two parameters, so then i can check for the 
same price but without the ordertype lower.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="price = 10" && "OrderType='P' ">
      <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
      <xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="price = 10">
      <td bgcolor="#cccccc">
      <xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="price = 10 and OrderType='P' ">
      <td bgcolor="#ff00ff">
      <xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="price = 10">
      <td bgcolor="#cccccc">
      <xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Well that was easy :) Thank you.

Comment: I might also recommend that you should write the TD and value-of statements outside the choose. in reality, you have a choose that is selecting the color. That choose should be inside an xsl:attribute.

Answer (score 1):

On my comment above, I would do that this way to save myself future efforts of changing "artist" or something like that. The choose relates solely to bgcolor and should be applied to only that (eliminating the otherwise condition by the way):

```
    <td>
        <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="price = 10 and OrderType='P' ">
                    <xsl:text>#ff00ff</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="price = 10">
                    <xsl:text>#cccccc</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
    </td>
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but keep in mind that if neither condition is met, then you'll have an empty `bgcolor` attribute.

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct and in HTML ... not so bad, in XSL FO a no-no. I should know better. You could always but the otherwise back in and use a default color or transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the previous answers, I'd also suggest putting your styling information into CSS, incase you want more than just the background to change at a later stage. Also, you don't *need* the `<xsl:text>` elements, they just keep whitespace to a minimum, but this shouldn't be as much of an issue in attributes as your think.

Also, where possible I like using *attribute value templates* to keep the XSL as close to what the output would be as possible, but that is purely a stylistic choice.

```
<xsl:variable name="cellClass">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="price = 10 and OrderType='P' ">
            cellPriceTenAndP
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="price = 10">
            cellPriceTen
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<td class="{$cellClass}">
    <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
</td>
```